# Subplot using hold and elseif in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, subplot

I have a problem while subplot my graphics.
Can't plot over the old graphic in object(axes) in my GUI.

The code:

```
if get(handles.checkerro,'Value') == 1
    plot(handles.axes4,tempo,real(Erro)','r')
    hold on
elseif get(handles.checkcalc,'Value') == 1
    plot(handles.axes4,tempo,real(Signal)')
    hold on
elseif get(handles.checksignal,'Value') == 1
    plot(handles.axes4,tempo,data)
end
```

checkerro, checkcalc and checksignal is ckeckboxes (GUI object)

Erro, Signal and tempo is matrices of the same size.

When I have ckeckerro and checkcalc (example) selected, can see only tempo vs real(Erro) ploted.

I await help.

thank

Comment: are you trying to replace the previous graph with the new one, or add it to the graph?

Answer (score 2):

The flow control statements `if ... elseif ...` are of the type [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). In pseudo code it means:

```
if A is true
    then A
otherwise if B is true
    then only B
end
```

You probably just want:

```
if get(handles.checkerro,'Value') == 1
    plot(handles.axes4,tempo,real(Erro)','r')
    hold on
end

if get(handles.checkcalc,'Value') == 1
    plot(handles.axes4,tempo,real(Signal)')
    hold on
end

if get(handles.checksignal,'Value') == 1
    plot(handles.axes4,tempo,data)
end
```